# "document cannot be resolved" error Android SDK webview getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, android, webview, document, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to click the "search" button on my layout & it will invoke a click to the google search button inside the webview.

```
webview.evaljs(document.getElementsByClassName("google search button blah").click());
```

however now eclipse is telling me

> Document cannot be resolved.

Anyone know how to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no evaljs function in standard Android SDK. So does "document". Eclipse will complain those no standard SDK references unless you import those extra jar file or library correctly. 

why don't you try quoting your parameter inside evaljs function? I guess your function needs string.

Comment: Well, if you know of another way to invoke a click to a button inside the webview without evaljs please share.

Comment: webview.loadUrl() will be just fine. I'll post answer below.

Comment: Okay. I thought about that, but doesn't it take you off your current webview page?

Comment: It won't. Loading javascript will not take you to another page unless your javascript is designed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to develop with Titanium Mobile SDK as evaljs is not part of official Android SDK. 
So my best guess to solve the problem with Eclipse complaining about Document cannot be resolved is

```
webview.evaljs("document.getElementsByClassName('google search button blah').click();");
```

If you want to go without Titanium Mobile SDK, you can always use loadUrl method of webview. Here is how to

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByClassName('google search button blah').click();})()");
```

Make sure your element can be found by the class name.

Comment: Would you know how to make this work on twitter mobile for clicking the follow button? I'm not sure how I could get the "follow" button classname though. Also, I am using eclipse.

Comment: You have to see twitter mobile page source and find out the id/class/name of follow button. 
When you know the class name, just use above code and replace class name. It shall work.

Comment: Do you know how to get a source code from the iphone or android? I don't know how to access twitter mobile on a desktop, & I'm not sure even if I did, if it would put out the same source as on a phone.

Comment: I am not sure about iphone. For android, there are some application which let you see the page source of specified url. Here is what I use https://market.android.com/details?id=com.apklabs.android.HTMLSourceViewerLite

Comment: Ok, I just downloaded it says <input type="submit" value="Follow" class="friend-actions-btn"/> but... the "block" button also has the same class. What should I use?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with trial and error. Hope you can figure out.

Comment: I'm using this code... `webview.evalJS('var element = document.getElementsByClassName("friend-actions-btn")[0];var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");evt.initEvent("click", true, true);element.dispatchEvent(evt);');` & I'm still getting the "invalid character constant" for ' rite here... evalJS('var element

Comment: please exchange usage of double quote and single quote. In java, you need to use double quote for String.

Comment: I changed everything over & now I'm getting a "The method evalJS(String) is undefined for the type WebView" error

Comment: As I said in the answer, evalJS(String) is not in official android SDK. So please make sure you have correct environment setup for Titanium Mobile SDK.

Comment: I'm using eclipse. What should I do?

Comment: Most simple way is to use second method (loadurl method) I gave you above.

Comment: I'm using that second code you gave me & none of the class's from the twitter follow button or anything around it is working. I also tried the class of the google button & other button's on google (the images link at the top) & I tried ask.com button's, also I tried getElementById and nothing is working.